# C++ overloading operators difference between == and <

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Could anybody explain me what is the difference between overload `==` and `<`?

For example, if I use a map:

```
map<Type, int> a();

friend bool operator<(const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs);

friend bool operator==(const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs);
```

And I implement both operators, when I call:

```
a.find(value);
```

The operator function of `==` is being called? I think not. I debugged and saw that `<` is called, but why? What should be the behavior of the operator function of `<`?

I come from Java where the method `equals` is called and is pretty simple to understand the behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator==` overloads the `==` operator (and no other); `operator<`
overloads the `<` operator (and no other).

`std::map` is defined to use `std::less` (and only `std::less`) by
default, and `std::less` is defined to use `<` by default.  In general,
however, I would recommend **not** overloading `operator<` unless
ordered comparison makes sense for your class, in which case, you should
overload all six comparison operators, in a coherent fashion.
Otherwise, you can specify a comparison functional type as an additional
template argument to `std::map`; the comparison functional object should
define a strict weak ordering relationship.  If the type is designed to 
be used as a key, but the ordering is still purely arbitrary, you might
specialize `std::less`.

As for Java, without operator overloading, it obviously can't use `<`;
by default, `SortedMap` (the Java equivalent to `std::map`) requires the
keys to be Comparable, however, which in turn requires a `compare`
function, which returns a value `<`, `==` or `>` 0, depending on whether
`this` is `<`, `==` or `>` than other.  I'll admit that I find this a
little bit more logical, but the difference is very, very small.  (The
rationale behind the C++ decision is that build-in types like `int` or
`double` can be used as keys.  In Java, you'ld have to box them.)

Comment: so when a use map<Type, int> and I dont implement any comparison function what is the comparison of Type that c++ does?

Comment: @thiagoh C++ would use `bool operator<` for `Type` by default, if that exists. If it doesn't, and you provide no comparison, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @thiagoh Whatever you tell it to.  The type of the comparison operator is an argument to the template, and the value (instance) is an argument to the constructor.  Both arguments have defaults: the type defaults to `std::less<KeyType>`, and the value defaults to `Cmp()` (where `Cmp` is the type of the comparison).  But these are just defaults.  And except for a `KeyType` of `std::string`, I've found it rare to use the defaults.  Most user defined types do not have a natural ordering.

Comment: so.. @JamesKanze when i dont give any parameter c++ uses `bool operator<` of Type? i think so.. but how i implement an `equal` behavior like java?

Comment: @thiagoh When you don't specify a comparison function, the standard uses `std::less<KeyType>`.  Which in turn used `<` unless you provide a specialization (and for pointers, where the compiler is required to make `std::less` have defined and consistent behavior even if the two pointers do not point into the same array).

Comment: @thiagoh I'm not sure what you mean by an `equal` behavior like Java?  The default behavior (in `Object`) of Java's `equal()` would be roughly the equivalent of comparing the addresses of objects in C++, except that C++ uses value semantics, so the addresses are always different.  And `SortedMap` (Java's equivalent to `std::map`) doesn't use `equal()`, it uses `compare()` by default (but as in C++, you can, and probably usually should set it to something different).

Answer (score 3):

The requirements that the C++ standard places on [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) mean that it is implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree. This means that some kind of ordering comparison between elements must be available. In the case of `std::map`, the requirement is a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), and the default is a less-than comparison. This is all that is required to arrange elements in a binary tree, and the equality condition is met when one element (call it A) is not less than another one (call it B), and the converse is also true, i.e. B is not less than A. An equality comparison could have been used, but this would open some scope for inconsistency. If you look at hash tables, such as [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you will find that an equality comparison is indeed required, although this is only to resolve collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<` is needed, because the find operation bases on the inner implementation of map (on the tree). To be able to find in complexity better than linear, it can't have to compare with every element.

A good example of the *similar* algorithm is [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). As you can see in sample pseudocode, it doesn't use the identity operator at all.

Comment: a equals b if neither a < b nor b < a, I suppose. It's only a guess.

Comment: @JohnB The relationship `!op(a, b) && !op(b, a)` is required to define an equivalence relationship, yes.  (On the other hand, the premise that `<` is necessary is completely false, and most of the keys I've used other than `std::string` have not supported `<`.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::map<T, U>` has such behaviour, it uses `std::less<T>` functor or your functor for many operations.

Behaviour can be different, but usual checks that lhs is less than rhs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because map is implemented as a balanced tree. Use unordered_map if you require a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is an ordered container, therefore it needs an `operator <` to define the order of elements.

A separate `operator ==` is not needed because it is implemented in terms of `operator <`, `a==b` being equivalent to `!a<b && !b<a`