# C++ std::set Find function overloading == operator

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I am using sets.  I use a custom struct as the key.  I am inserting a value and trying to find the inserted value.  But it never seems to find the element.

I have overridden both the == operator and the < operator.

Here is the code of the structure:

```
struct distance_t
{
 public:
int id;
double distance;

bool operator<(const distance_t& rhs) const
{
    if(distance < rhs.distance)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

bool operator==( const distance_t& rhs) 
{
    if(id == rhs.id)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
};
```

And this is the code of main

```
int main()
{
    set<distance_t> currentSet;

    distance_t insertDistance;
    insertDistance.id =1;
    insertDistance.distance = 0.5;

    currentSet.insert(insertDistance);

    distance_t findDistance;
    findDistance.id = 1;

    assert(currentSet.find(findDistance) != currentSet.end());
}
```

It always fails in the assert statement.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit -Ok now I understand that it does not use the == operator at all.  Here is what I want.  I need the data structure to be ordered by distance.  But I should be able to remove it using the id.  Is there any clean way or already existing datastructure to do this?

Comment: A style suggestion: where you have `if (expr) return true; else return false;` you could instead simply do `return expr;`

Comment: What's wrong with just `return id < rhs.id;` or `return id == rhs.id;`?  (I'd consider using an `if` to return `true` or `false` an anti-pattern.  The comparison operators return a `bool`, and testing a `bool` just to return it's value doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @Blastfurnace You don't need the parentheses, either.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, I was trying not to transform his original code too much.

Comment: agreed.  I had that first.  But since it dint work, I tried different notations (even though it was a moot point.. worth a try!)

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069991/c-overloading-operators-difference-between-and/12070047#12070047

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman Just trying random changes when something doesn't work isn't a good technique.  If something doesn't work, don't change anything until you understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It fails because your less-than comparison uses `distance_t::distance`, which you are not setting in `findDistance`:

```
distance_t findDistance;
findDistance.id = 1;
```

[std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) does not use `operator==` for anything. It only uses `operator<`. So you would have to change it's logic to use `distance_t::id`.

If you want to search by `id` without changing the set's ordering, you can use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
set<distance_t>::iterator it = std::find(currentSet.begin(), 
                                         currentSet.end(), 
                                         findDistance);
```

This will use your `operator==`. Bear in mind that this has linear time complexity.

Comment: I want to use distance to order the elements but want the id to find the element.  Is that possible at all?

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman ordering is used for look-up (set is a binary tree). So it is not possible to have decoupled ordering and lookup. You could incorporate `id` into the ordering logic, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman You can make `operator<` look at distance first, and if they're equal, look at id. That would preserve the order you're looking for. (And also change `operator==` to look at both fields.) But that does mean you cannot search if you only have the id.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman: `set::find` uses the set's ordering to perform a logarithmic lookup. You could iterate over the entire set looking for the desired `id` instead.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman you can search by `id` using `std::find`. I added an example.

Comment: Put the objects into a `set` ordered by the distance, and maintain a map of `id`s to entries in the set.  (If the types had identity, and were dynamically allocated, I'd suggest several `set <distance_t, order>`, with different ordering functions.  But from the little you've shown, I don't think that this is the case.)

Answer (score 4):

Because `operator==` is not invoked at all. Comparing elements is like:

```
!(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

In other words, it uses `operator<`.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't assigned a value to `findDistance.distance` the result of the less then comparison is undefined.

Note that your definitions of the equality and less then comparison operators is dangerous, because it is easy to define instances of `distance_t` where their result is inconsistent. One example is two instances with the same distance but different id's.