# I want to use C++ map, for the purpose of storing 4 coordinates against a rectangle id,can anyone give an example?

Tags: c++, dictionary

suppose I have a rectangle which has id:1 and coordinates, 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0. Can I use C++ Map data structure for this? or any other ways out. I also need to find the key(or id) given the co-ordinates.

Comment: Doesn't boost have a map where you can go both ways? A `boost::whateverMapItIs<unsigned int, Rect>` would probably do the trick.

Comment: You have just one rectangle? Or many? Will you be adding more of them over time? Deleting them too? How many approximately? What do you mean by mapping from coordinates to keys exactly... how are the coordinates represented (fully, or partially etc.) in that case?

Comment: There are several ways. And if you want to look a rectangle up by its coordinates, you're faced with the problem of comparing floating-point numbers for equality, which is a little dangerous.

Comment: I found the boost one. It's [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html).

Comment: @jogo, no I have many rectangles, each one is mapped to an unique id and the rectangle has 4 coordinates, the lower ones and the upper ones.Not interested to delete for now. Just one to read from a file which has lx ly hx hy rect_id at each line and store it to a map.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct rectangle
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
};

std::map< int, rectangle >myMap;
           |
          the ID
```

Access by ID, find by value. Though you will be able to search by value only if all the coords are provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find coordinate by ID, you can use SingerOfTheFall's answer. If you find to find ID by coordinate, you need to override operator equals for rectangle.

Comment: You should mention that this requires a `std::map<rectangle,int>` in addition to the `std::map` mentioned in SingerOfTheFall's answer. Also, you are overloading the wrong operator (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069991/c-overloading-operators-difference-between-and).

Comment: would you please elaborate the operator overloading with an example in this case?